# What does a GLX equivalent of eglBindTexImage look like?

Tags: opengl, egl, glx

On making an in-process compositor for embedded use the EGL eglBindTexImage looks like a promising solution for enabling the compositor to use OpenGL itself without messing with any client OpenGL context. It'd be serving clients a pbuffer and associated GL context secretly bound a GL object in the compositor GL context.

However I'd like for this to work on host too which runs X. Closest thing I can find in the extensions list is [GLX_EXT_texture_from_pixmap](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL/extensions/EXT/GLX_EXT_texture_from_pixmap.txt), but then I'd have to use a pixmap instead of pbuffer and manage a bunch of caveats such as y-direction.

Any alternatives I might have missed?

Comment: Is there some reason you can't use an FBO to accomplish the same thing?

Comment: @NicolBolas It would not be transparent to the client. For what I know the FBO would need be allocated inside the client context and bound using glBindFramebuffer. Any client operation on framebuffers would need be aware of this (as 0 is no longer the name of the "default" framebuffer), or alternatively have all framebuffer operations hooked and manipulated to take care of it. The hooking would require crafty linking, or wrapper code, and either case interfere with debugging tools on host. In short, it's possible but not preferrable because it would mess with client GL context.